# Microsoft Word Add-in Parse mktcmpid Not Working

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I have posted a question on the MSDN "publishing apps for office store" forum [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ba907882-165d-41b8-9c97-437ec2008564/track-word-addin-download-with-mktcmpid-not-working?forum=officestore) and unfortunately haven't received a response so I thought I'd try Stackoverflow to see if anyone else has had similar issues.

I've developed an add-in for Word and have followed the instructions on this [page](https://dev.office.com/officestore/docs/promote-your-office-store-solution) to track the performance of my advertising campaigns that drive people to my add-in on the Office Store.

Specifically the section under the "Track your campaign performance and customize your add-in for targeted audiences" header, specifies how a developer should be able to access a `mktcmpid` from the `Settings` object through Office.js.

If I attempt to add a `mktcmpid` parameter to the Office Store URL for my add-in, and then attempt to parse this value from within the add-in's code like below, I always get `null` for a value.

```
if (Office.context.document.settings) { 
   return Office.context.document.settings.get("Microsoft.Office.CampaignId"); 
}
```

Additionally, the value for `Office.context.document.settings.get("Microsoft.Office.CampaignId");` is always `null`. Does this feature (being able to pass in an arbitrary `mktcmpid` via the Office Store URL, directly to the add-in) work for anyone else?

This paragraph from the above article seems to suggest that this should work as I am attempting to use it:

> Adding these parameters to your campaign URL will enable us to provide
>   more information about your campaign's user funnel. The  mktcmpid
>   parameter is passed all the way to the launch document. This allows
>   you to customize the first user experience of your free Word, Excel,
>   or PowerPoint add-in to, for example, display a specific splash screen
>   or welcome message to your targeted audience. When the document loads
>   for the targeted user, the  mktcmpid parameter is available in the
>   Settings object of the add-in as a Microsoft.Office.CampaignId, in
>   Office clients where the Settings object is supported. Use the
>   following code to read the Microsoft.Office.CampaignId from the
>   Settings object.
>
> ```
> if (Office.context.document.settings) { 
>                return Office.context.document.settings.get("Microsoft.Office.CampaignId"); 
>                 }
> ```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Sam, Our engineers took a look at this and have a question for you: Are both the mktcmpid & mktvid values set when calling the apps page?
The mktvid must be your provider ID. You can get this value in the URL shown when you click on your provider name on any of your apps or add-ins on the Office Store. The format will be PNXXXXXXXXX
The mktcmpid can be any value you choose - as long as it's within character limit. These parameters have to be passed on your app page, not on the install page.

Comment: Hi there, thanks the comment. So yes, here is an example of a URL that I have tried: 

`https://store.office.com/en-001/app.aspx?assetid=WA104381028&mktcmpid=twitter&mktvid=PN104379508&ui=en-US&rs=en-001&ad=US&appredirect=false`

Does this url link to the app page or the install page? I'm unclear on the difference. 

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Sam, This links to the apps page. From here, you should be able to click add and get the document through the install flow. Once you've done that the API call to get the campaign ID from the document should return the value. 
We're happy to connect with you offline to try and resolve. If you have our email address, please shoot us an email. If you don't have our address, let us know your developer name and we'll be in touch.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info and for following up. So unfortunately even after following this link and downloading the add-in, the campaign id parameter comes back as null. It would be great to follow up offline, thank you. Unfortunately I don't have your email address. You can reach me at smorris@woodpeckerweb.com. Looking forward to hearing from you!

Comment: Thanks so much! We finally figured out that there seems to be a character minimum on the `mktcmpid` parameter. Unsure what it is right now but they are looking into it. In the meantime I will be changing all of my `mktcmpid` parameters to be longer. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the awesome help from the support team we finally figured out that there seems to be a character minimum on the mktcmpid parameter. Unsure what it is right now but they are looking into it. In the meantime I will be changing all of my mktcmpid parameters to be longer. Thanks a ton!